# Unable to run GCP terraform commands from GitHub Actions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam

I have setup keyless authentication for my Github Actions pipeline using Workload Identity Federation by following the [official tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enabling-keyless-authentication-from-github-actions)

When running a terraform init command from my pipeline I get the following error:

```
│ Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: querying Cloud Storage failed: Get "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/lws-dev-common-bucket/o?alt=json&delimiter=%2F&pageToken=&prefix=global%2Fnetworking.state%2F&prettyPrint=false&projection=full&versions=false": oauth2/google: status code 403: {
│   "error": {
│     "code": 403,
│     "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
│     "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
│     "details": [
│       {
│         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│         "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
│         "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
│         "metadata": {
│           "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
│         }
│       }
│     ]
│   }
│ }
```

I have ensured that the service account that I am using has proper permissions including:

- Cloud Run Admin
- Cloud Run Service Agent

Below is a snippet of my pipeline code:

```
- id: 'auth'
  name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
  uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0.4.0'
  with:
    workload_identity_provider: 'projects/385050593732/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my-pool/providers/my-provider'
    service_account: 'lws-d-iac-sa@lefewaresolutions-poc.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

- name: Terraform Init
  working-directory: ./Terraform/QuickStartDeployments/EKSCluster
  run: terraform init
```

and my terraform code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.89.0"
    }
  }

  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "lws-dev-common-bucket"
    prefix  = "global/networking.state"
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
}


module "vpc" {
  source  = "../../Modules/VPC"

  project_id = var.project_id
  region     = "us-west1"
  vpc_name   = var.vpc_name
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the following roles on my service account, and it still does not work: Cloud Run Service Agent, Compute Admin, Compute Engine Service Agent, Editor, Service Account OpenID Connect Identity Token Creator, Service Account Token Creator, Service Account User.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and was able to fix it by granting the service account `Service Account Token Creator` role in the project IAM page manually

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if your service account doesn't have permission to access the storage bucket where your terraform state file is stored, or if your service account doesn't have the `Workload Identity User` role set properly.